# mule Config for app not found

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I have mule flow, trying to deploy it, it says that "Config for app not found"

I have created a dummy mule-config.xml under src/main/app, given below. My flow is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <flow name="webservicesFlow1" doc:name="webservicesFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="slmule2.corp.local" port="8088" path="rest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="com.rest.sample.RestComponent"/>
        </jersey:resources>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

mule-deploy.properties

```
redeployment.enabled=true
encoding=UTF-8
domain=default
config.resources=webservices.xml
```

**mule-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.0/mule.xsd">

    <!-- empty config to avoid the hot deployment classloader choking on a missing config file -->

</mule>
```

## ***Error message:***

```
    ERROR 2014-06-12 12:58:06,575 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ + Failed to deploy app + + 
'webservices-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-v20140612-12+57', + + see below + 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
org.mule.module.launcher.InstallException: Config for app 'historydata-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-
v20140612-12+57' not found: /apps/mulesoft/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.2/apps
/webservices-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-v20140612-12+57/webservices.xml at 
org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.install(DefaultMuleApplication.j
ava:107) at 
org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.install(ApplicationWrapper.java:79) 
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:42) at 
org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.guardedDeploy(MuleDeploymentService.java:454)
 at 
org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.deployApplication(MuleDeploymentService.java:
191) at 
org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.deployExplodedApp(MuleDeploymentService.java:
708) at 
org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.deployExplodedApps(MuleDeploymentService.java
:661) at 
org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.access$400(MuleDeploymentService.java:57) at 
org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService$AppDirWatcher.run(MuleDeploymentService.java:
808) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) at 
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThr
eadPoolExecutor.java:178) at 
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPool
Executor.java:293) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) INFO 2014-06-12 12:58:07,859 [2132436410@qtp-
1158879031-6] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService: ================== Request to 
Undeploy Application: ambrosehistorydata-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-v20140612-12+57 INFO 2014-06-12 
12:58:07,860 [2132436410@qtp-1158879031-6] 
org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'webservices-1.0.0-
SNAPSHOT-v20140612-12+57' never started, nothing to dispose of INFO 2014-0
```

I am using mule studio 3.5.0 and mule-ee 3.4.

Comment: What is this `namehistory.xml` file that makes the deploy fail?

Comment: it was having another xml file in the application.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
when you build your zip, you should zip files, not a directory ...
Dan

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you have the same issue as the OP? Can you elaborate a litle more on how zipping a directory can cause the same issue (same error) ?

Comment: how we can make auto .zip file once we deploy.

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all, it must be deleted because it did not tell anything about how to solve the problem, it is referenced by google as the first answer but it should not be voted up definitly here.

Comment: The error described in the original post can be caused by zipping up a mule app and then copying the zip file to another Mule environment if you create the zip while in the directory {MULE_HOME}/apps.  Daniel is specifying that if the error occurred in this context the solution is to create the Zip file from {MULE_HOME}/apps/{APP_NAME}.  i.e. so the files in the contained zip do not contain the APP_NAME directory.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes javaw.exe doesn't seem to let go of a running project and seems to lock access to the config file. Killing javaw.exe and rerunning the project again fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Mule configuration file (src/main/app/app-config-file.xml), you can specify the properties file you want to load.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${environment.name}.properties" />
```

This is the description of the attribute location :

**Attribute : location**

> The location of the properties file to resolve placeholders against,
>   as a Spring resource location: a URL, a   "classpath:" pseudo URL, or
>   a relative file path. Multiple locations may be specified, separated
>   by commas. If   neither location nor properties-ref is specified,
>   placeholders will be resolved against system properties.

${environment.name} must be a system environment variable. You need to make sure the system where you are deploying your app contains that variable. I think you can also specify it in the Maven build, if you are using Maven (clean install -Denvironment.name=test). You can try.

To test locally, right click on your project, select run as, select run configurations, click on Environment tab, add your variable "environment.name" and the value "local" (without quotation marks) and make sure your local.properties file exists in a location added to the build path. It can be src/main/app for example or in the resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too.
My solution, i believe, was simpler.
Instead of exporting the project somehow and then try to deploy it by uploading a zipped file through the browser, I deployed it through Anypoint studio itself.

1. Right click on the project
2. Anypoint platform
3. Deploy to cloud
4. Sign in with your credentials (if not signed in already)
5. Choose the proper application and runtime environment then hit deploy.